# Expression of type Int doesn't conform to expected type 0

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have the following piece of code

```scala
object Solution {

  def solution(prices: Array[Int]): Int = {
    prices.foldLeft((prices.headOption.getOrElse(0), 0)) { (tuple, price) =>
      (Math.min(tuple._1, price), Math.max(tuple._2, price - tuple._1))
    }._2
  }
}
```

IntelliJ Idea is highlighting `Math.max(tuple._2, price - tuple._1)` saying that "Expression of type Int doesn't conform to expected type 0".

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Community Edition), Ubuntu

Scala plugin: v2019.1.9

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try updating to [2019.1.4](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2019.1+EAP) with latest Scala plugin and File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.. | Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the inferred type of your `foldLeft` expression is `(Int, 0.type)`, where `0.type` is a [literal type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html) because of the `0`, in the 2nd position in this tuple `(prices.headOption.getOrElse(0), 0)`.

Do you happen to use scala 2.13? This is the version where this feature has been added.

On my machine, `IntelliJ` highlight the code, with the same error as you, but I can still run the code, therefore I'd say it's a bug on intelliJ where the type is inferred to narrowly.

The other expression `Math.min(tuple._1, price)` doesn't have that error, because the first element of the resulting tuple of the `foldLeft` is inferred to `Int` (because of the expression `prices.headOption.getOrElse(0)`).

If you do want to get rid of the `IntelliJ` error message you can use a `type ascription`:

```scala
def solution(prices: Array[Int]): Int = {
    prices.foldLeft[(Int, Int)]((prices.headOption.getOrElse(0), 0)) { (tuple, price) =>
      (Math.min(tuple._1, price), Math.max(tuple._2, price - tuple._1))
    }._2
  }
```

or

```scala
    def solution(prices: Array[Int]): Int = {
      prices.foldLeft((prices.headOption.getOrElse(0), 0: Int)) { (tuple, price) =>
        (Math.min(tuple._1, price), Math.max(tuple._2, price - tuple._1))
      }._2
    }
```

Comment: yes, it works that way. But I need an explanation. Is this a bug in Idea? or something else? Why `Math.min` is ok?

Comment: yes, I just upgraded Scala to 2.13. On my machine the code also runs. The highlight was just bothering me. Thanks